# calling an activity when an item is pressed in a ListView in an Android app

Tags: android, listview, click

I would like to call one of the activities that I have written in my android app, when I press an item in a ListView.
The code that I want to use is this:

```
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          .
          .
          .

          Intent lp = new Intent(this, myFirst.class);
          startActivity(lp);
        }
      });
```

However it I get error related to the following two lines:

```
          Intent lp = new Intent(this, myFirst.class);
          startActivity(lp);
```

basically I want to call "myFirst" activity when an item on my list view is pressed.
What is the correct way of calling "myFirst" activity here?

Thanks for the help.

TJ

Comment: please post your manifest.xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are passing an instance of `OnItemClickListener` to your intent.
Try to pass the instance of `Actiity`

```
Intent lp = new Intent(YourActivity.this, myFirst.class);
startActivity(lp);
```

Comment: And make sure you have defined your `myFirst` as an `Activity` in Manifest. By convention the class name must start with capital character. (i.e `MyFirst.class`)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. I changed the "this" to "MyActivity.this" and the error went away.

Comment: Glad that you fixed your problem.Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help you in this. 'this' may not be refering to your current activity.

Instead of 'this', use the following.

NameOfTheActivityThatIsCurrentlyOpen.this(i.e., the filename.this). This always works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was basically the same answer as what @Tanamy suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this way

```
    Intent lp = new Intent(<filename>.this,myFirst.class);
```

or

```
Intent lp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),myFirst.class);
lp.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(lp);
```